# connecting another db2 instance in same php file in BlueMix

Tags: php, db2, ibm-cloud

I connect to a db using this code

//parse VCAP_SERVICES Environment variable

```
$vcap_services = $_ENV["VCAP_SERVICES"];
$services_json = json_decode($vcap_services,true);
$sqldb = $services_json["sqldb"];
if (empty($sqldb)) {
    echo "No sqldb service instance is bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance";
    return;
}

//Get Credentials object (db,host,port,username,password)
$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=".
   $sqldb_config["db"].
   ";HOSTNAME=".
   $sqldb_config["host"].
   ";PORT=".
   $sqldb_config["port"].
   ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=".
   $sqldb_config["username"].
   ";PWD=".
   $sqldb_config["password"].
   ";";
```

then I do "my thing" and close the connection with

```
db2_close($conn);
```

then when I try to connect to another instance of the db2 db by using the same connection code but changing the middle argument in this line:

```
$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];
```

the connection does not work. The two parts of code work just fine separately. It's when I put the code in the same file in that order that it causes this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've closed a connection you have to open a new one (using the code you're already using) in order to access to the DB again. It is correct to close the connection after each 'logic' group of queries.

Comment: I use the whole big connection code, then I close the connection. then I run the WHOLE code again but just changing that one middle argument in that one line..

Comment: well, not really an error. the db2_num_rows function in the second part fot the code echos to "0" ... and it should be "10" .... and as I wrote.. IF i just remove the first connection and the suff I do in it the second connection works fine and te db2_num_rows finctions shows 10

Comment: Umberto, you know what. not sure why, maybe you can explain. but I just removed the 
    db2_close($conn);
from between the 2 parts of the code and now it works just fine....

Comment: What you should do is "1.open the connection 2.query the DB 3.close the connection" for each "block". The issue you experienced seems to be related to the fact that you closed the connection before the second block and never open it again. For this reason when you removed the db2_close($conn); line the connection was still open when executing the second block. That's the reason why it worked then.